# Virtual proof of accommodation letter for the Czech Republic

Tags: visa, czech-republic

I am a non-EU citizen, with a job offer in the Czech Republic.

One of the documents needed for a visa is a proof of accommodation. This is quite annoying, as I don't want to rent an apartment before coming to the Czech Republic.

While looking for advice on the internet, I came across a few companies that claim to sell a "virtual proof of accommodation letter". This is essentially a letter saying I have an accommodation by this company, but it seems to me this is not real accommodation.

Is this a legit way to get the visa?

Comment: That sounds fraudulent.  How about a ho(s)tel for the first days/weeks?

Comment: Thanks, a hotel is not good because I need a proof of a long term accommodation for at least 6 months.

Answer (score 2):

Czech consulates have seen all kinds of fraud over the years and they will know your accommodation proof isn't real from a mile away. Your options are thus:

1. Ask your company to help out with securing the required documentation
2. Bite the bullet and rent an apartment remotely. You can always find a new one later on after moving

Comment: A good rule of thumb is "If you can find this shady service, the visa officer surely can as well (and it's his job to do so)."